# I'm using the asciidoc formatting in JBake. How can I use a custom backend for the asciidoc to html generation?

Tags: asciidoctor, jbake

I'm using the asciidoc formatting in JBake. I'm using version 2.4.0 of JBake.

All is working well, but i want to make some changes in the HTML generated from the asciidoc content. Normally in Asciidoctor you can specify the template_dirs option for custom backends.

I tried to do the same within JBake by adding the following to the jbake.properties file.

```
asciidoctor.option.template_dirs=src/custom-asciidoctor-backends/erb/html5
```

The directory src/custom-asciidoctor-backends/erb/html5 contains the original backend, without any changes on my part.

This gives me the following error

An unexpected error occurred: (NoMethodError) asciidoctor: FAILED: : Failed to parse source, undefined method `each' for "src/custom-asciidoctor-backends/erb/html5":String

So my question is how can I configure JBake to use a custom backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 2.4.0 in JBake this is not possible.
A [issue](https://github.com/jbake-org/jbake/issues/252) has been raised at the JBake project.